# CMake cannot generate a safe linker search path - yocto 2.4

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, linker, yocto

I have 2 yocto pkgs that can be successfully compiled with gcc 5.4, cmake 3.6.1 on yocto 2.0.2 but I'm facing the following issue with: gcc 6.3, cmake 3.6.1 on yocto 2.4 .

After some research, I observed that yocto changed the sysroot structure (sysroot per package instead of a common sysroot).
The error looks like this:

```
CMake Warning at src/mytest/CMakeLists.txt:71 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe linker search path for target mytest because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

link library [libpthread.so] in /local/build2/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/mytest/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /local/build2/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/mylib/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib


  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

Leading to linking error: `ld: cannot find /lib/libpthread.so.0`

I observed in some cmake generated files that mylib package exports its libraries with hardcoded pkg name, that will be later used by test pkg:

```
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/usr/include/;/{_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "-lpthread; mylib; /local/build2/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/mylib/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libpthread.so;"
)
```

Is there any way to avoid this kind of duplication? Or to remove the full paths from cmake generated files?

Comment: Could you show your `target_link_libraries()` command for mylib? Why is `pthread` mentioned twice (once with relative, once with absolute path)?

Comment: Please be informed that from 2.4 Yocto release, shared tmp/sysroots is not exist any more [docs](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#structure-build-tmp-sysroots)